# Android - Catch firewall block exception

Tags: android, firewall

I am developing one android application. I am using my web link to download some files from server. In this I want to catch if firewall blocks my web link. is there anyway to catch firewall blocks exception?

Comment: What is the httpresponse for a requeset blocked by the firewall?

Comment: In my firewall my web link is not blocked. But if it blocks to the user, I want to display them a "Toast" or "Alert" ,"Your Firewall blocks the url". In this case how can I catch this?

Comment: So whjen a client tries to access it , what does it get? 403? 404? what?

Comment: sorry. I am new this so don't know about that firewall responses.

Comment: If the firewall is blocking your network traffic your java code that reaches out to the server should be getting an Exception of some sort, perhaps IOException, check your try/catch blocks. You are probably already catching the Exception, you just need to add your Toast message to the catch block.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The status is 403 @smk